# What is wrong with this equations?

Tags: factoring

so our math teacher told us how 2 * 2 = 5 today and we were like :O

I thought really hard to disprove this but it seems correct, would someone please tell me how is this possible!

proving 2 * 2 = 5 :

```
we know that : 25 - 25 = 0
and : 20 - 20 = 0
so : 25 - 25 = 20 - 20
now we can factor this equation into : 5 ( 5 - 5 ) = 4 ( 5 - 5 )
now both ( 5 - 5 )s are identical right? so : 5x = 4x
therefore : 5 = 2 * 2 , 5 = 2 + 2 , 10 = 8 , 15 = 12 ,...
```

oh and another thing : proving 2 + 2 = 2

```
lets say : x = 2 and y = 2
so : y^2 = xy
and : x^2 - y^2 = x^2 - xy
so : ( x - y ) ( x + y ) = x ( x - y )
we divide both sides by ( x - y ) and we have : x + y = x
now if we plug in numbers we have : 2 + 2 = 2
```

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_fallacy#Division_by_zero

Comment: where did I divide anything by zero??

Comment: (5-5) and (x-y) are both zero.

Comment: oh I see, so is this equation wrong? or is it a valid principle?

Comment: You can't divide by zero factor.

Comment: No, it is not valid, and the false conclusion to each argument shows why.  You can check that $5(5-5)=4(5-5)$ is correct and the step to $5=4$ (the $x$'s are a red herring) is not correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should know that:

$ax=bx \implies a =b$

is not valid unless we know that $x \neq 0$.

That is: $$ax = bx \Leftrightarrow ax - bx = 0$$
$$\Leftrightarrow x(a-b) = 0$$

what is the conclusion ? $x = 0$ or $a=b$

In both reasoning above he exploited this fact to drive such conclusions.

Comment: @LarsH thanks, ;)

Comment: Technically, I think you could argue that the implication could hold if $a$ happened to be equal to $b$, even when $x = 0$. How about this wording... (I'll edit the answer... rollback if you want.)

Answer (score 0):

The formulation logically is that $(AB = 0) \Leftrightarrow (A=0) \text{ or }(B=0)$. One, both, or neither of the secondary equations may have a solution. The problem is that in the cited example, the valid secondary equation was ignored and only the one with no solution was kept.

Incidentally, *there's nothing wrong with coming up with an equation that says* $5=4$. It's perfectly fine, and in fact, you often *want* to end up with something like that. It's the whole idea behind proof by contradiction. The proper conclusion, though, is **NOT** that $5$ and $4$ are equal; instead, since it is obviously false, you should conclude that *the secondary equation leading to this falsehood has no solution*.